# How do I apply the style of all TextInputEditText of android application

Tags: android, android-view, android-resources, android-theme, android-styles

I want to set custom font size of hint of `TextInputEditText`. I have an style which I want to apply to my all `TextInputEditText`.

It is not applying on my `TextInputEditText`. Can anyone help me where I am missing something ?

### styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".login.AuthenticationActivity"
        android:label="@string/login_screen_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

### layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/access_code_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/login_participation_access_code"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I would try putting the changes inside AppTheme.

Comment: Just tried and this code works ok. Issue must be somewhere else

Comment: @HonzaMusil Yup.. Something I am missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either directly apply `app:hintTextAppearance` to `TextInputLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance"
    ...
    >
```

Or change your activity's or application's theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:theme="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"
```

Comment: I can not set my application/activity them `android:theme="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"`. Can we add this in item of AppTheme ? If so then how ?

Comment: `Can we add this in item of AppTheme?` What do you mean?

Comment: Like this  `<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>`

Comment: Your `Widget.Design.TextInputLayout` theme does exactly what you say: it overrides `hintTextAppearance`.

Comment: Ahh I see. I made this change https://pastebin.com/km2V8si3 it is still not working

Comment: @Williams, you are missing [the concept of inheritance](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance) for themes.

Comment: I set `AppTheme` on my application like `<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

Comment: When you are declaring a new theme and overriding a value in it, you have to apply exactly that theme to your activity. But you are applying `AppTheme`, no change will happen.

Comment: @Williams, given the code you have posted in your question, if you apply suggestions in my answer you will succeed. I.e., make your activity's theme be `android:theme="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"`

Comment: Yup. It made changes in the font size of float label not the hint of `TextInputEditText`. I am looking to change font size of hint of TextInputEditText

Comment: Because the initial text is not `TextInputEditText`, it's the `TextView` inside `TextInputEditText`. Apply appropriate style to `TextView`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139616/discussion-between-williams-and-azizbekian).